# How to configure the SQL Server with SQL Assessment?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I added the SQL Assessment solution in my OMS workspace for collecting the SQL server health information.

For that I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-sql-assessment#installing-and-configuring-the-solution) documentation, even I added the SQL Assessment solution in my OMS workspace still I am not getting any data from my SQL Server.

[image]

How can I configure the SQL Server with SQL Assessment?

Comment: You already posted a link to the step-by-step guide. If you have a problem with it, post a *specific* question. "I don't understand it" is not a specific question

Comment: I read the above documentation but I am little bit confusing for where to install agents and where to run the T-SQL, power shell scripts.